# How to resize UITextView and then UITableViewCell based on UITextView's content

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, uitableview

I've seen some similar questions, but none of the other solutions that were working for others are working for me, so please don't mark this as a duplicate. I've been trying alternate solutions for three days with no luck.

My contractor requested, as part of the app, that I have a tab that allows the user to read tweets with a specific hashtag. I am pulling all of the data from Twitter fine, and when I use a generic cell (i.e. height 200, UITextView height of 180) all of the data comes in and displays fine. However, this obviously does not look very professional, and I'd like to change it to dynamically resize the height of the cells.

The UI in Interface Builder looks like this (the blue highlight is the UITextView): [image: Cell's UI]

Can anyone tell me how to resize the cell and text view in order to properly display the content? I'm fairly lost at this point.

Comment: do you use autolayout or s&s? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [this method](http://blog.jldagon.me/blog/2013/12/07/auto-layout-and-uitableview-cells/). It 99% similar to your problem. Try first to make it work only with Label, and then add other UIViews

Here is some thought regarding problem's solution.

I'll copy some part of code from link above.

First of all I'll speak about simplified table cell with just a Label. Add 4 constraints in Storyboard (trailing and leading, top and bottom spacing between label and superview).

In such case, height of cell should be the following:

> Content view height = Top constraint + label height + Bottom
>   constraint

```
- (void)configureCell:(CustomCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.customLabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"custom_cell"]
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    // here is HUGE mistake in link above! Be careful!
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return height + 1;
}
```

Here is what code does:

```
1. Configuring the content of the cell
2. Forcing a layout of the cell to apply constraints
3. Getting the height of the contentView, computed using Auto-Layout. We can’t directly call systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize: on the cell because the constraints we’ve set up are relative to the content view. Finally, we use UILayoutFittingCompressedSize to get the smallest size fitting the content.
4. Adding a bonus 1. We’ve computed the content view height but we actually need to return… the cell height here. And it’s 1 pixel higher, because of the separator, which height is 1 pt (0.5 for Retina screens on iOS 7, to be exact).
```

**Discussion on this solution**
This solution involves more calculation, then asking `[NSString -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:]`. But in my opinion latter method makes you move all your design (constraints, font setting, etc) right to code, because it gives you only Label height, not whole cell.

Imagine you have 10pt indent from top and bottom. With new update you've decided to change it to 5. You have to change your code, or it won't reflect changes.

Of course, calculating height for each cell involves more calculation. Fortunatelly, in iOs7 new UITableView delegate method was introduced: `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`. It greatly reduce calculations and improves performance.

I do believe, that you should use method described in this post (despite the fact, that there could be some performance problems with iOs6. I think there is only 5-10% of iOs6 users nowadays and decreasing.)

Comment: In my experience, using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` is not usually performant or flexible enough to work in a general app.  This is especially true if you need to support older versions of iOS that don't use the `estimatedHeight` methods.  Also, link-only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow because the link may 404 in the future, so you may wish to expand on your answer with at least an outline of the linked approach in case the link goes down in the future.

Comment: @AaronBrager yeap, you're right. Under 7.0 without estimatedHeight it would have some problem with performance on huge number of rows. But afaik it's about 10% of all users. Oppositely. using boundingRectWithSize will make your design (from IB, I think) goes into code. Changing design (font size, family, spacing etc) should be repeated in code.

Comment: Those are all valid points, which I think would improve your answer if you feel like expanding it.

Comment: Agreed - this solution is best suited for iOS 7.0 + due to the new `UITableView` delegate method. However, you can gain performance benefits by caching the calculated height values. See `Performance` section in this blog post for another dev's experience with it: http://johnszumski.com/blog/auto-layout-for-table-view-cells-with-dynamic-heights

Comment: Had to modify a couple of things, but definitely a workable solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do two things:

1. Calculate what the height of the cell should be, and return it in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  (You can use `[NSString -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:]` to get the size of your text.)  Yes, you'll need to do a little geometry / addition.
2. Configure your UITextView to automatically expand to appropriate fill space in its superview.  You can do this using auto-layout, springs and struts, or manual layout.